# It be not until ~ that ~

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, conjunctions, emphasis

> It was not until after we had been on the highway for several hours that Peter asked me if I wanted stop at a restaurant for a bite to eat.

In my opinion, It ~ that ~ is a sentence that emphasize after “that” and be not (A) until ~ means not A before ~.

My questions are
1. How is two conjunction used continuously?
2. Explanations of the sentence of It be not until ~ that ~. Is it “not A until B” + “It ~ that ~”?

Comment: *It ~ that ~* is a structure with no context.  There has to be more in it to specify what is going on:  *It was **before** that moment ...*  or *It was **after** that incident ...*  Your example includes only the structure *It was **not until** ~ that ~*

Comment: @Andrew What is the class of after in the sentence of question? How is it located just after until, which is conjunction?

Comment: "After we had been on the highway for several hours" is a phrase, possibly a *prepositional phrase* ... but I don't really care much for the fine distinctions of grammar terminology.

Comment: It's a [**cleft sentence**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/word-order-and-focus/cleft-sentences-it-was-in-june-we-got-married): Time expressions can be emphasised with **It was not until ...**
and **It was only when ....**
_It was not until I met you that I knew real happiness.
It was only when I read her letter that I realised what
was happening._

Comment: I cannot understand your actual question or the title to it.

Answer (score 0):

"It ~ that ~" is a structure with no context. There has to be more in it to specify what is going on:

> **It** was before X **that** Y

or

> **It** was after X **that** Y

Your example only explains the timeline of events, with no particular emphasis on the part of the sentence after "that".  It's also not quite correct:

> It was not until after we had been on the highway for several hours that Peter asked me if I wanted **to** stop at a restaurant for a bite to eat.

The entire structure is  possibly a "cleft sentence" (according to Mv Log), while, "After we had been on the highway for several hours," is possibly a prepositional phrase.

Comment: I think the OP forgot to put in the to.